# Can MediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer() be used to assess the success of decoding

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

Code largely following the [MediaCodec sample](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/DecodeEditEncodeTest.java) is not generating video.
Instead of asking a general question, let me ask a specific one:  Does it mean the decoding is working if MediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer() return successfully without generating an exception. I am trying to determine whether the problem is attributed to the decoder or the surface setup.

```
MediaCodec.BufferInfo bi = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
int iOutputBufferIndex = _mcDecoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bi, TIMEOUT_USEC);
if (iOutputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
    // no output available yet
} else if (iOutputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
    _bbDecoderOutputBuffers = _mcDecoder.getOutputBuffers();
 } else if (iOutputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
    MediaFormat newFormat = _mcDecoder.getOutputFormat();
} else if (iOutputBufferIndex < 0) {
    //log error;
} else {
    //Can the following statement be used to assess the success of the decoding?  
    _mcDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(iOutputBufferIndex, true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of the buffer tell you if decoding is working.  Releasing the buffer just tells the system that you're done looking at it.

If you configured a `Surface` for output, you will appear to get zero-byte buffers of data.  The actual data is rendered to the `Surface` when the `render` flag is set (which you appear to have done).  You won't see actual contents unless the `Surface` is tied to the UI somehow.  (Note the current set of examples largely don't try to display anything.)

If you didn't configure a `Surface`, you should see nonzero quantities of data in each output buffer you dequeue.

**Update** from the chat session: OP was setting an opaque background on a `SurfaceView`.  `SurfaceView` is actually a transparent window with the Surface layered behind it, so making it opaque obscured the video.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying a lot of things which the document does not seem to intend. Yes, BufferInfo shows the size is zero. MediaFormat of the output is the following: 
{height=600, what=1869968451, color-format=19, slice-height=0, crop-left=0, width=800, crop-bottom=599, crop-top=0, mime=video/raw, stride=0, crop-right=799}.  Now, I assume the decoder is working. I pass the Surface of a SurfaceView obtained in surfaceCreated() via SurfaceHolder. The sample code uses OutputSurface that goes through fairly elaborate process to render it.  Is it necessary? Is my current way too simple?

Comment: It should be possible to use a SurfaceHolder the same way you would with MediaPlayer.  I'm curious about the "mime=video/raw" though... what format is the encoded video in?

Comment: Yes, I am using exactly the same surface as used by a MediaPlayer, but I have taken the MediaPlayer out of the code. The video is H.264 encoded. I have saved the video (a fairly complicate process) to MP4 files that can be played by VLC and other video players.  My point is that I am probably feeding the decoder the correct data.  Could you let me know if the output data is JPEG? I will try decoding it to bitmap so your confirmation will be very helpful.  By the way, the SurfaceView is customized one, but he customization really does not do anything (legacy story).

Comment: (1) For H.264 encoded video, you should be using the "video/avc" MIME type.  (2) You can't feed a .mp4 file directly into MediaCodec.  It requires a raw H.264 elementary stream, broken into packets -- are you using MediaExtractor?  (3) The output is a raw frame of data, not JPEG; the format is specified by the color-format value in the MediaFormat.  See the buffer-to-buffer code in the EncodeDecodeTest example on bigflake.

Comment: No, it is not from an MP4 file. I meant that I produce MP4 files with exactly the same data fed to MediaCodec. The data are well formatted NAL units preceded by SPS and PPS. The decoder is created as following: MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");  At this point of time, I still assume the decoder is working properly.  The issue lies with the rendering.

Comment: My mistake -- "video/raw" refers to the decoded format, not the encoded format, so what you show looks reasonable.  On a Nexus 10, logging the "format changed" MediaFormat in EncodeDecodeTest, I get color-format=19 (COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar) for the buffer-to-buffer tests, and color-format=263 (internal) for buffer-to-surface.  Nexus 7 uses 19 and 256.  So I'm wondering about color-format=19 in your MediaFormat.  What device are you using?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40387/discussion-between-hong-and-fadden)